# Insert into a table from multiple tables which are alike in Pattern

Tags: mysql

I have 1900 tables like table_1, table_2 and ........... which structure are same.

I want to insert all data to a new table table_all.

I know using UNION ALL I can do that but that's no useful as number of tables are large.

Comment: That seems to be a terrible table design. Why do you have so many  similar tables?

Comment: It's an automated process, data got separated on each day as the regular data volume is high. My tables are like cdr_date

Comment: You could try building dinamically server side  the sql code string select the tables  name from from the db dictionary of the tables

Answer (score 0):

I made a procedure and it's working fine.

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS insert_from_multiple_table;
CREATE PROCEDURE insert_from_multiple_table()
Begin
DECLARE tableCount INT DEFAULT 0;
SELECT COUNT(*)
INTO tableCount
FROM  information_schema.`TABLES` where table_name like 'table_%' and table_Schema='your_db';

```
WHILE tableCount>0 DO
    SET @dt_ncv = CONCAT("table_",tableCount);
    SET @cntstmt = CONCAT( "insert into alltable select * FROM ",@dt_ncv);
    
    #select @cntstmt;
    PREPARE ncv_count_stmt FROM @cntstmt;
    EXECUTE ncv_count_stmt;

    SET tableCount = tableCount-1;
END WHILE   ;
```

END